# Don't Starve Together LAN MP

Tags: dont-starve, networking, dont-starve-together

So, I am playing *Don't Starve Together* in offline mode, and I would like to play with my friends at our LAN parties. The problem is that the server I host won't show up.

What I tried:

- Hamachi
- Show LAN = ON

What it might be:

- The PC is wired to the router, and the laptop is wirelessly connected.

Comment: Is the modem the wireless router as well?

Comment: Yes it is. sorry

Comment: Im dumb. I typed modem instead of router.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using Evolve or Tunngle instead of Hamachi. I use Tunngle to host and play with my friend. These are more reliable ways of setting up virtual LANs. Just get in one room with person you want to play!

Answer (score -1):

You must use the server filter to find local servers. There is nothing more that you need.